# SSH over OpenVPN without Admin rights

Tags: windows, ssh, openvpn

Would it be possible to install openvpn on a machine without admin rights? Of course it wouldn't be possible to change the network routings but this shouldn't be a problem. I only want to run a ssh client on it like putty. How would I configure the ssh client to use the vpn connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *could* be possible technically, but the OpenVPN software doesn't support being used that way. (It'd need to have its own TCP implementation, at minimum, and that'd likely make it more complex than it's worth.)

If you cannot change the routing table, you won't be able to connect through the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

You can install openvpn without admin rights but you **cannot** install the TAP-driver without admin rights .. so the VPN would not work anyway.